# Повторяющиеся данные

Tags: python

Перебрал кучу вариантов, не могу заставить работать Ариму. Есть данные идеально подходящие для прогнозирования. Но после трейн-тест не могу написать чтобы получить прогноз на несколько значений вперед. Как я понимаю решение на 3 строчки, возможно кто то сталкивался и знает.

```
from pandas import read_csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('series.csv')
df.columns = ['x', 'y']

df.y.plot()

train=df.y[0:100] 
test=df.y[100:]

from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing

model = ExponentialSmoothing(train, seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods=12).fit()
pred = model.predict(start=test.index[0], end=test.index[-1])

model.plot()
pred.plot()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, Экспоненциальное сглаживание и Хольт-Винтерс - это не ARIMA, разумеется.

Во-вторых:
А откуда вы взяли, что у вас периодичность сезонности 12? На глаз? Я вот четко вижу (вернее не я, конечно, а анализ автокорреляции показывает), что сезонность у вас 10.
И вот вам результат:

```
model = ExponentialSmoothing(train, seasonal='add', seasonal_periods=10).fit()
pred = model.predict(start=test.index[0], end=test.index[-1])
pred.plot()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: (S)ARIMA -  это другая группа методов. AвтоРегрессия-Интегрирование-Скользящее Среднее. S впереди - еще и сезонность в добавок.